# Filling Time Series Data Array With Previous Values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have a time series for stock prices. The data isn't always continuous, some days are missing. I'd like to fill in these days with the previous value. How can I do that efficiently?

There may be over a thousand markets with 1000+ days of data. Each day has an object of timestamps and pricing.

I want to do things like get the prices for every market on a particular day and sort them.

I'm not sure if it's better to fill in all the missing days by inserting timestamps and prices where needed? (It expands the memory usage but probably faster for data access - I don't know how much memory this needs to be honest. 1000 markets, 1000 days, with 6 object keys. If a number is 8 bytes then that's about 43Mb + whatever object overheads there are?).

**Or** to try return the previous match which would require searching every array for the matching timestamp. This seems expensive if I want to do this for every day of the data.

[Sample data set (jsbin)](http://jsbin.com/honijicodu/edit?html,js,console,output)

```js
let data = {
  "name": "MARKET",
  "values": [{
    "time": 1440338400000,
    "close": 0.142163,
    "high": 0.152869,
    "low": 0.142163,
    "open": 0.152221,
    "volume": 14.2163,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440511200000,
    "close": 0.158082,
    "high": 0.161828,
    "low": 0.15139,
    "open": 0.154371,
    "volume": 441.882,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440597600000,
    "close": 0.162958,
    "high": 0.165483,
    "low": 0.15688,
    "open": 0.158235,
    "volume": 335.53,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440684000000,
    "close": 0.16487,
    "high": 0.167594,
    "low": 0.160171,
    "open": 0.162908,
    "volume": 492.134,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440770400000,
    "close": 0.162612,
    "high": 0.166171,
    "low": 0.162327,
    "open": 0.164979,
    "volume": 81.1436,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440856800000,
    "close": 0.156701,
    "high": 0.161385,
    "low": 0.155568,
    "open": 0.161316,
    "volume": 514.921,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1440943200000,
    "close": 0.144589,
    "high": 0.157018,
    "low": 0.141987,
    "open": 0.156943,
    "volume": 635.154,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441029600000,
    "close": 0.145655,
    "high": 0.146195,
    "low": 0.142581,
    "open": 0.144715,
    "volume": 10.1958,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441116000000,
    "close": 0.142958,
    "high": 0.146204,
    "low": 0.142701,
    "open": 0.145595,
    "volume": 0.544275,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441202400000,
    "close": 0.148987,
    "high": 0.148987,
    "low": 0.141326,
    "open": 0.142983,
    "volume": 58.1051,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441288800000,
    "close": 0.15025,
    "high": 0.150856,
    "low": 0.148987,
    "open": 0.148987,
    "volume": 34.4072,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441375200000,
    "close": 0.155935,
    "high": 0.156681,
    "low": 0.15228,
    "open": 0.152503,
    "volume": 0.155935,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441461600000,
    "close": 0.159049,
    "high": 0.160032,
    "low": 0.155711,
    "open": 0.155836,
    "volume": 0.159049,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441634400000,
    "close": 0.163826,
    "high": 0.16474,
    "low": 0.162861,
    "open": 0.164304,
    "volume": 327.651,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441720800000,
    "close": 0.124591,
    "high": 0.16437,
    "low": 0.124427,
    "open": 0.163697,
    "volume": 1558.32,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441807200000,
    "close": 0.115118,
    "high": 0.125665,
    "low": 0.115,
    "open": 0.124679,
    "volume": 110.436,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441893600000,
    "close": 0.10203,
    "high": 0.115274,
    "low": 0.101593,
    "open": 0.115047,
    "volume": 1795.72,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1441980000000,
    "close": 0.101996,
    "high": 0.102003,
    "low": 0.101886,
    "open": 0.102003,
    "volume": 1795.14,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442066400000,
    "close": 0.104842,
    "high": 0.106246,
    "low": 0.104305,
    "open": 0.106246,
    "volume": 2.09684,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442152800000,
    "close": 0.105386,
    "high": 0.106185,
    "low": 0.103682,
    "open": 0.104886,
    "volume": 2192.04,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442239200000,
    "close": 0.102747,
    "high": 0.114521,
    "low": 0.102498,
    "open": 0.105317,
    "volume": 21.0632,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442325600000,
    "close": 0.0736399,
    "high": 0.105086,
    "low": 0.0697372,
    "open": 0.102713,
    "volume": 863.28,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442412000000,
    "close": 0.0805882,
    "high": 0.0805882,
    "low": 0.0736,
    "open": 0.073644,
    "volume": 79.9028,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442498400000,
    "close": 0.0882002,
    "high": 0.0885284,
    "low": 0.0805882,
    "open": 0.0805882,
    "volume": 52.9201,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442584800000,
    "close": 0.102387,
    "high": 0.102535,
    "low": 0.0878508,
    "open": 0.0881813,
    "volume": 738.121,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442671200000,
    "close": 0.102663,
    "high": 0.10276,
    "low": 0.102129,
    "open": 0.102387,
    "volume": 10.2663,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442757600000,
    "close": 0.104525,
    "high": 0.106224,
    "low": 0.104265,
    "open": 0.106224,
    "volume": 72.0357,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442844000000,
    "close": 0.109941,
    "high": 0.110287,
    "low": 0.104422,
    "open": 0.104472,
    "volume": 5.49706,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1442930400000,
    "close": 0.109915,
    "high": 0.110532,
    "low": 0.109467,
    "open": 0.110108,
    "volume": 5.49574,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443016800000,
    "close": 0.115694,
    "high": 0.116243,
    "low": 0.113882,
    "open": 0.114151,
    "volume": 23.1389,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443103200000,
    "close": 0.116584,
    "high": 0.116939,
    "low": 0.115274,
    "open": 0.115608,
    "volume": 23.3168,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443189600000,
    "close": 0.119464,
    "high": 0.119717,
    "low": 0.118964,
    "open": 0.119519,
    "volume": 11.9464,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443276000000,
    "close": 0.122498,
    "high": 0.122824,
    "low": 0.118839,
    "open": 0.119362,
    "volume": 12.2498,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443362400000,
    "close": 0.125336,
    "high": 0.125755,
    "low": 0.122345,
    "open": 0.122539,
    "volume": 12.5336,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443535200000,
    "close": 0.118549,
    "high": 0.119365,
    "low": 0.118333,
    "open": 0.119131,
    "volume": 1460.31,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443621600000,
    "close": 0.120841,
    "high": 0.121297,
    "low": 0.118471,
    "open": 0.118521,
    "volume": 12.0841,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1443708000000,
    "close": 0.121266,
    "high": 0.121307,
    "low": 0.120696,
    "open": 0.120696,
    "volume": 12.1266,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1444053600000,
    "close": 0.124926,
    "high": 0.125369,
    "low": 0.122085,
    "open": 0.122188,
    "volume": 0.249852,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1444140000000,
    "close": 0.124018,
    "high": 0.12524,
    "low": 0.124018,
    "open": 0.124926,
    "volume": 0.248037,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1444312800000,
    "close": 0.127015,
    "high": 0.12717,
    "low": 0.126854,
    "open": 0.127056,
    "volume": 269.89,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1444399200000,
    "close": 0.129375,
    "high": 0.129437,
    "low": 0.126736,
    "open": 0.126915,
    "volume": 12.9375,
    "marketCap": 0
  }, {
    "time": 1444485600000,
    "close": 0.129097,
    "high": 0.129523,
    "low": 0.129063,
    "open": 0.12927,
    "volume": 12.9097,
    "marketCap": 0
  }]
};

data.values.forEach(value => {
  let date = new Date(value.time)
  console.log(date.toString())
})
```

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Sample data set added

Comment: @JoshuaJenkins— +350 lines of object data isn't "minimal". You haven't supplied any code related to your question, just a loop that prints the date.

Comment: @RobG my question is should I duplicate missing dates or look up the previous date every time I want a value?

Comment: As for minimal. The 2nd value skips a date.

Comment: I'd loop over the array and insert missing values. Just use whatever algorithm seems best. If it doesn't perform well, then look for alternatives. What improves performance in one host might not in another, or even be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternate solution for this, Re-Sampling of data. 
Have a look https://content.pivotal.io/blog/time-series-analysis-part-3-resampling-and-interpolation

Comment: This is excellent. Sometimes the solution to the problem is being able to define exactly what it is. That article explains all the issues that I'm facing.

Comment: I have face similar problem in past. I thought this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will be to loop through the array backward and splice in the missing timeframe data. The data will be a reference to the last value seen which will mean the timestamp will be incorrect, but since intervals are uniform (daily), I can just use the array index to get the correct data I'm after. I assume a reference like this will reduce unneeded duplicate memory usage too.